# giving a id to anchor tag doesnt execute the view in django

Tags: django

Here's some code from my template.

```
 <li ><a id="b" href="{% url graph1 "pf_daywise" %}">POWERFACTOR</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="c" href="{% url graph1 "pf_daywise" %}" >DAYWISE</a></li>
        <li><a id="d" href="{% url graph1 "pf_monthwise" %}">MONTHWISE</a></li>

     </ul>
  </li>
```

If I give a id to the anchor tag it doesn execute the href part. can sumbody help. I am actually calling a view where graph1 is the name of the url.

This is the relevant line from my url.conf

```
url(r'^graphs/(?P<param>[A-za-z]*)/$','display_graph',name="graph1"),
```

Comment: ya. it doesn take any action when i give a id.

Comment: url(r'^graphs/(?P<param>[A-za-z]*)/$','display_graph',name="graph1"),

Comment: maybe the problem is in your view and url. your url does not take underscore, just letters or 1 word only. We cannot solve your problem if your question is incomplete. You must post what you have done, your all codes connected to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Catherine mentions in the comments, your URL pattern does not match underscores, so "pf_daywise" is not a valid value for `param`. Maybe you meant this:

```
url(r'^graphs/(?P<param>\w*)/$','display_graph',name="graph1"),
```

Comment: Your pattern as written would match only something like `graphs/    /`; you probably meant `\S` or `[^\s]`, not `\s`. :)

Comment: @Dougal good catch: I actually meant `\w`, ie any alphanumeric character or underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li><a id="b" href="{% url graph1 'pf_daywise' %}">POWERFACTOR</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="c" href="{% url graph1 'pf_daywise' %}">DAYWISE</a></li>
        <li><a id="d" href="{% url graph1 'pf_monthwise' %}">MONTHWISE</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Shot in the dark (I'd have to test), but I'm assuming "doesn't execute" means that, when you look at the source, you don't see the href attribute, or it's blank, something equally weird.

My bet is that double-quotes inside other double-quotes is throwing Django's tag parser off.

Which, if true, would be a bug in Django's parser. But that's entirely possible.

Just adding an `id` wouldn't cause a problem otherwise.

Comment: if i remove the id part it does execute. but i need to id part actually to do sum action when i click the anchor tag

Comment: Review the generated HTML, is the href there and filled in correctly?